# Unexpected end of file from server, Neo4j Rest client

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I'm writing a Neo4j Client, I'm running Neo4j client and server on two different machines (windows operating system). Sometimes (after many times) that I'm issuing a query (I'm using java-rest-bind api and issuing Cypher queries), an exception of Unexpected end of file from server raises. Is there any explanation? (My whole data size is 10G but I'm accessing 1 node and counting about 200 relationships per transaction)
This is the full exception:

```
Stdout: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Stdout:     at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
Stdout:     at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.UserAgent$1.handle(UserAgent.java:68)
Stdout:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
Stdout:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
Stdout:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
Stdout:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:553)
Stdout:     at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestRequest.post(ExecutingRestRequest.java:151)
Stdout:     at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:547)
Stdout:     at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:568)
Stdout:     at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:235)
Stdout:     at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
Stdout:     at Neo4j.Neo4jRestClient2.viewProfile(Neo4jRestClient2.java:440)
Stdout:     at edu.usc.bg.base.DBWrapper.viewProfile(DBWrapper.java:101)
Stdout:     at edu.usc.bg.workloads.CoreWorkload.doActionGetProfile(CoreWorkload.java:2329)
Stdout:     at edu.usc.bg.workloads.CoreWorkload.doTransaction(CoreWorkload.java:1061)
Stdout:     at edu.usc.bg.base.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:201)
Stdout: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
Stdout:     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
Stdout:     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
Stdout:     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
Stdout:     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
Stdout:     at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:240)
Stdout:     at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
Stdout:     ... 15 more
```

Comment: Please check the posts.. you may find the answers.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.net.SocketException%3A+Unexpected+end+of+file+from+server     .there is mention of wait time and trying from different server.

Comment: can you also check your server logs? In data/log/console.log and data/graph.db/messsages.log